# Adding Text to Image or 3D Space HTML

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js

My goal is to create a web app that works very similar to those websites that allow you to add custom text to a mug and your text appears in realtime on the image of the mug.

Ideally I'd like to have my "image" be a 3d object that can be rotated as well, but I'd settle for just a 2d image if need be. The text would also need to be rotated at times.

Can anyone point me to tutorials that demonstrate this or something similar? I'm also looking for suggestions as to the best tools and languages to use to accomplish this - Javascript/Three.js, other frameworks, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074263/how-to-add-text-into-along-the-object-using-three-js I think that could be helpful

Comment: You are best off to read three.js documentation. if you want just plain old Canvas (no webGl). Good realtime FX can be done eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/40999097/3877726 second example and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499923/3877726 for simplified projected 3D using a more formalised (non standard) mathematical model. But you can not beat webGL for high quality realtime 3D content. If you have not done any 3D coding in the past then three.js is the best place to start.